# Brute Force Optimization

Tags: c#, optimization, plugins, brute-force

I am developing an application which uses a plug-ins, the plug-ins are developed by independent developers. I need to optimize the parameters for the plug-in using brute force.

```
public class Parameter
{
    public double Start { get; set; }
    public double Step { get; set; }
    public double Stop { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class Plugin
{
    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; private set; }

    public Plugin()
    {
        Parameters = new List<Parameter>()
        {
            new Parameter() { Start = 1, Step = 1, Stop = 2 },
            new Parameter() { Start = 3, Step = 1, Stop = 4 }
        };
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        double sum = 0;
        foreach (var parameter in Parameters)
        {
            sum += parameter.Value;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum = " + sum);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Plugin();
        test.Parameters[0].Value = test.Parameters[0].Start;
        test.Parameters[1].Value = test.Parameters[1].Start;
        test.Execute();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But unfortunately I can't invent algorithm of optimization of parameters. 
Under brute force, I mean

[image]

```
Parameter1 = 1
Parameter2 = 3

Parameter1 = 1
Parameter2 = 4

Parameter1 = 2
Parameter2 = 3

Parameter1 = 2
Parameter2 = 4
```

The main problem consists in that that the quantity of parameters in a plug-in can be any.
Maybe you could suggest which algorithm to use in this case.

P.S.: sorry for my bad English.

-----addition--------

In other words.

I made a new example that illustrates what I want to do.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Plugin();

        for (double parameter_0 = test.Parameters[0].Start; parameter_0 <= test.Parameters[0].Stop; parameter_0+= test.Parameters[0].Step)
        {
            for (double parameter_1 = test.Parameters[1].Start; parameter_1 <= test.Parameters[1].Stop; parameter_1 += test.Parameters[1].Step)
            {
                test.Parameters[0].Value = parameter_0;
                test.Parameters[1].Value = parameter_1;
                test.Execute();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Plugin
{
    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; private set; }

    public Plugin()
    {
        Parameters = new List<Parameter>()
        {
            new Parameter() { Start = 1, Value = 1, Step = 1, Stop = 2 },
            new Parameter() { Start = 3, Value = 3, Step = 1, Stop = 4 }
        };
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Parameters[0].Value) + " " + Convert.ToString(Parameters[1].Value));
    }
}
```

This code works correctly but unfortunately if the plugin to add a new parameter the code will break. I need to invent an algorithm which is not sensitive to the number of parameters.
I know that I can use recursion but then I can not use multi-threading.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you want to know? Alternative methods of optimization? How to brute force test with all possible parameters? How to find all possible parameters?

Comment: Are you trying to test the plug-ins?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you need a cartesian products of your the parameters lists.

To do a cartesian product you can use this method:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> 
              CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) => 
      from accseq in accumulator 
      from item in sequence 
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})); 
}
```

(from [Computing a Cartesian Product with LINQ](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/) by Eric Lippert)

Then you need to create out of each parameters the lists of parameters values and apply the cartesian product to it. Since it looks like you are only interested in the Start and Stop values you can do the following:

```
var combinations = 
    CartesianProduct<double>(parameters.Select(x=> new [] {x.Start, x.Stop});
```